# Excel Consolidate Data not working - Data does not merge

Tags: excel

For some reason I cannot get the Excel consolidation function to work. My data refuses to merge.

All of the numbers in my column are formatted as dollar amounts.

My original data set looks like this:

```
__________________
|NAME    |DOLLARS |
|Andrew  |  $10.00|
|Michael |  $10.00|
|Emma    |  $10.00|
|Andrew  |  $10.00|
|Michael |  $10.00|
|Emma    |  $10.00|
-------------------
```

But after I run it through the Consolidate Data function, where I made sure to select all of the data + the headers, and selected "sum", my results look like this:

```
__________________
|NAME    |DOLLARS |
|        |  $10.00|
|        |  $10.00|
|        |  $10.00|
|        |  $10.00|
|        |  $10.00|
|        |  $10.00|
-------------------
```

I have no idea why it's not working. I tried following several tutorials to the letter, as well as scouring the internet for solutions, but everything I tried did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't consolidate letters by 'summing' them. So it leaves them blank as this would error.

You have to specify that the first column isn't to be summed, but rather to be used as row labels. This is done by ticking

> Use labels in > Left column

You have already selected `Top row`. it is the option underneath:
[image]

This does result in no column name for the first column, but you could easily type that back in afterwards in the destination range.

**But** I have a feeling you might not actually want to use the consolidate tool. This is for consolidating multiple ranges of data into one. Your dataset only includes one range of values so would be pointless consolidating it.

More on consolidating can be ready here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I do actually need the consolidate tool though, because I'm trying to format about 10,000 rows of data. The example up above is simplified.

Comment: Ah - great. Good stuff.  Please tick the answer as the accepted answer if that has worked for you.